# Why two plots are not identical

Tags: matlab, plot, derivative

I am trying to plot functions in MATLAB. In the first plot I write a function and use the `gradient` command to plot the function. In second plot I have taken the derivative of a function and then plotted it. But the two plots are not identical. Where is the discrepancy?

MATLAB Code:

```
X=-1:.05:1;
T=-1:.05:1;
m=1+1*1i;
[x,t]=meshgrid(X,T);
r1=m.*sin(x+4.*t);
dr1=gradient(r1);
dt=gradient(t);
dr1dt=dr1./min(diff(T));
td=t(2:end);

surf(x,t,abs(dr1dt));
```

I have plotted it.

[image: plot of the first code]

Then I take the derivative of `r1` w.r.t `t` and then plot the function. i.e.,

```
X=-1:.05:1;
T=-1:.05:1;
m=1+1*1i;
[x,t]=meshgrid(X,T);
r1=4.*m.*cos(x+4.*t);

surf(x,t,abs(r1)');
```

[image: plot of the secondcode]

I have found that there is difference of amplitude in these plots. Why are the two plots not identical?

Comment: You didn't take the derivative correctly

Comment: @ Ben, actually there was $cos$ instead of $sin$. Its a typo mistake

Comment: Ordinarily you can fix mistakes like that by using the "edit" link under your question.  But right now another user's edits are pending, so it may not allow you to make changes until those are accepted or rejected.

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between the derivative of a continuous function and an approximation to the derivative determined using a discretized version of that function? Or are the differences really important here? Maybe if you upload the two plots it’s be easier to see what kind of differences we’re talking about here.

Comment: @ Luengo, I have uploaded the plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `gradient`, with one output argument, computes the partial derivative in the x direction. Thus, what you compute in the first bit of code is d/dx r1, not d/dt r1. With two output arguments it computes both the x and the y derivatives.

In the second bit of code, the computed derivative is transposed, leading to swapping the x and t axes.

The following bit of code fixes both these errors:

```matlab
X=-1:.05:1;
T=-1:.05:1;
m=1+1*1i;
[x,t]=meshgrid(X,T);
r1=m.*sin(x+4.*t);

[dr1dx,dr1dt]=gradient(r1);
dr1dx=dr1dx/mean(diff(X));
dr1dt=dr1dt/mean(diff(T));

dr1dt_true=4.*m.*cos(x+4.*t);

figure
subplot(1,2,1)
surf(x,t,abs(dr1dt));
xlabel('x')
ylabel('t')
title('discrete approximation')
subplot(1,2,2)
surf(x,t,abs(dr1dt_true));
xlabel('x')
ylabel('t')
title('analytical')
```

[image: output of code above]